# Актуальность баг-репортов о локализации мобильных приложений SO

Tags: поддержка, локализация, мобильное-приложение

Периодически пользуюсь мобильными приложениями для SO, как под Android, так и под iOS. При этом заметно, что элементы интерфейса приложения (кнопки, поля ввода и т.д.) не локализованы вовсе, а некоторые сообщения локализованы частично (например, причины закрытия), хотя в web-версии перевод уже доступен полностью. В связи с этим вопрос: насколько вообще актуально сейчас  добавлять на Мету темы с дефектами по локализации мобильных приложений SO, будут ли они приняты к рассмотрению в ближайшее время, или всё это еще настолько сыро, что пока идет работа над основным функционалом, а имеющаяся локализация пока что есть всего лишь побочный эффект организации хранения строк?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конкретном случае с мобильным приложением,

#### Нет, к сожалению мобильное приложение не поддерживает локализацию

И более того, как я понимаю, собирается совершенно из другой кодовой базы.

В общем случае,

#### Актуальны любые дефекты, касающиеся переводов существующего на сегодняшний день функционала сайта русскоязычного сообщества

Постараюсь раскрыть идею на примере.

На Transifex находятся все строки, относящиеся к движку в целом, включая несколько разделов, которые не поддерживаются в русскоязычном сообществе (например, Документация, История разработчика, Вакансии и т. д.). Все новые разделы проходят «обкатку» на англоязычном сайте. Большинство из них будут активированы в международных сообществах, как только они станут более или менее стабильными. Любые дефекты переводов, относящиеся к такому функционалу, можно опускать, так как не известно в каком виде данный функционал будет присутствовать в стабильной версии продукта (и будет ли присутствовать вообще).

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что если в каком-то месте локализация пролезла в мобильную версию (приложение, сайт), то отсутствие качественной локализации в этой части есть баг, о котором имеет смысл сообщить, так как он может быть исправлен через transifex и автоматически попадет в мобильную версию (приложение, сайт) без непосредственных изменений в коде самих приложения/сайта?

Comment: @alexolut Да, именно так! Единственное, иногда случается, что не все строки доступны на Transifex. В этом случае, мне необходимо запросить ответственных людей их туда добавить.

Comment: если это может быть реализовано заведомо быстрее, чем доработка моб.приложения, то это уже хорошо. Хотя, ведь если строки нет в transifex, это значит, что она захардкожена?

Comment: Еще раз уточнил. По–моему я ввел всех в заблуждение. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Странно, но в мобильном приложении например видны переведенные причины закрытия вопросов. То есть на момент выполнения этого действия, а когда вопрос уже закрыт, то причина указана на английском.

Comment: @alexolut Могу лишь предположить. Формулировки причин не по теме хранятся в базе (также в базе, в настройках сайта, хранится еще уйма строк). Скорее всего, они по API тянутся.

Comment: так вот эта база, она из trsnsifex получает строки? Ведь если какая-то локализация уже пролезла в мобильную версию, то значит ее можно сделать красиво в этой части.

Comment: В большинстве случаев – нет. То, что в базе, то в базе. На Transifex вынесены только статичные строки из кода и разметки. Настройки сайта – отдельная история.

Comment: а как русский перевод попал в базу?

Comment: Не до конца понял вопрос, Поясните, пожалуйста, какой именно перевод?

Comment: вот тему создавал даже: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3555/176217

Comment: удалось ли выяснить как эти строки попали в мобильные приложения?

Comment: @alexolut Потрес ребят: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233989/

Comment: история о том как перевод (неполноценный) попал в приложение не раскрыта.

Comment: Это ошибка разработчиков. Оказалось, что поскольку описания на всех сайтах одинаковые, было принято решение жестко закодировать их. Остальные строки причин закрытия подтягиваются через API.